# How can I prevent file copy in my usb stick?

Tags: usb, security

I want to prevent other users of copying my files from my usb stick. Is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 14):

Don't put the stick in their computer? Or encrypt the data. But of course you can't access it on their computer then.

But whenever the data on your usb stick can be read, it can be copied.

If you want to protect yourself against theft of the stick then encryption is the way to go. I recommend portable truecrypt with a file container for this.
If you want to protect against malicious computers from which you access your data you can't win.

Answer (score 0):

The USB stick that shipped with Macbook Air is read-only. I guess if they can do it, you can do it as well. Although people have found ways to make it writable with some low level tool, it is secure enough for regular use.

Comment: That would mean they can still read all his files. I think he doesn't want anyone to be able to even look at his files without his permission.