# Sharing content with a kill switch and that is hard to copy

Tags: copy-protection

I have been getting requests to share a copy of notes which I took in class for an exam day after tomorrow, but I'm faced with the realization that if I do they *will* be used with malicious intent by some classmates. I need a way to share these notes in such a way that I can flip a remote kill switch before the exam and ensure that they cannot be easily copied in other ways to smartphones. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: If this had a solution, it would be patented and the music industry would be implementing it.

Comment: True. I'm looking for a kind of "best effort" solution, though. One that will take considerable effort to get around in a single day (and therefore make it worth more to study than try and make a copy).

Comment: Your solution is to invite those that wish to see your notes to a study group without cell phones or cameras and simply study them. You cannot give out digital information and expect it to not be copyable.

Comment: If you think they will be misused, don't give them out. Simple. You don't need to give in to peer pressure. Spend your time revising not copying notes for people who should have taken their own.

Comment: Any digital file can be copied what you want does not exist.

Comment: There is no answer for this.  If they can read it, they can copy it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable copy in shared folder](http://superuser.com/questions/348592/how-to-disable-copy-in-shared-folder), [How can i prevent file copy in my usb stick?](http://superuser.com/questions/287874/how-can-i-prevent-file-copy-in-my-usb-stick)